# Friendly URL conflict with subfolders index.html

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have an .htaccess containing these mod_rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`
```

It works fine for my main project's friendly URLs, however I have a conflict when trying to access /subfolder/index.html through the URL /subfolder/ or /subfolder , it loops.

I've tried many things without success, I guess I have to use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` and then make the `RewriteRule` to index.html, but when I succeed with that then the URL / responded with a permission denied error.

How can I make subfolders go to it's own index.html and still have friendly URLs?

Clarification note: Friendly URLs doesn't and will never match an existing folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DirectoryIndex` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` together:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Before writing on SO I tried `DirectoryIndex` with index.html but without the index.php, this may be the reason why on my root folder I got the permission denied error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow very nice logic, +1 :)